# Google-Maps API blurred/not focused while Google-Maps is fine

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to embed a google-map with MAPS API V3. This works fine so far, but I got the problem that some areas are strangly blurred:

For example Ibiza, Spain in Maps API:

[image]

Looking at it in Google-Maps in the browser, all is fine:

[image]
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Ibiza,+Spain/@38.9148453,1.4037506,12671m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x1299476385093943:0x9064725cd8426d6

I first thought it might be a problem of my code, but looking at pages like http://www.siteway.de/maps-generator/ or http://www.gmapgis.com/ revealed that ALL implementations of the API seem to have this problem.

I added my code anyway, it's really plain & easy:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap'),
            {   center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.9148453,1.4037506),
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                scaleControl: true
            });

<div id="mymap" style="width:640px; height:480px;"></div>
```

The problem seem to appear on zoom-level 11 and 12 (perhaps on 10 as well, hard to say). Any idea what might be wrong? Or is Google using another quality for the images output by the API in comparison to Maps?

Comment: It would be interesting to test that with different browsers / OS / Maps API versions.

Comment: You are right. The images above where made with Chrome on Win7. I tested it with FF and IE on Win7 as well with the same effect. If someone could test "Ibiza City, Spain" with Zoom-Level 11 or 12 on  other OS would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everywhere has the same "problem" - then maybe it's not a problem, but a feature? Google Maps is serving different tiles - they can serve whatever tiles they want, it's their API - to embedded maps and APIV3 vs the one on their website. I'd doubt this is a bug, but try and report it and see if you get a response:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Of course Google can do what it wants, I was just wondering, because 2 different tiles means twice the storage-space (ok, Google would have enough of that I guess), but delivering bad quality when better quality exists isn't normally Googles intention.

Comment: @Werner - they aren't "bad quality". Bad quality would mean the same type of tile they deliver on their own map, but at a poor quality. The simple fact is, it is a different tile - the mountains on the tiles deliver to the API are of a different design than the mountains on the tiles they use on their own map.